# How to use "new" on an abstract class

Tags: c#

I've tried to search for other questions like mine but I can't find any good result
I'm trying to use a DLL that has a method that need to be called with a new class but that class is abstract.

thanks.

i tried to use new IClientHandler but it just errors

Comment: Only option to „new“ an abstract class is to define an anonymous implementation: `var x = new AbstractClass(){};`

Comment: You can define a class derived from the abstract class and instantiate that. Or maybe there is already such a class?

Comment: I expect the library has a derived class for you to instantiate.

Comment: You cannot instantiate an interface (`IClientHandler`). Instead, you must instantiate a non-abstract class implementing this interface. This class can also be derived from an abstract class possibly already implementing the interface.

Comment: IClientHandler is an interface, not an abstract class. Neither can be instantiated. Interfaces require implementations that can be instantiated and abstract classes must be extended by non-abstract classes that can be instantiated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to instantiate an abstract class in C# code. This is not possible, as an abstract class is a class that cannot be instantiated on its own. Instead, you would need to create a non-abstract class that extends the abstract class and then use that to create an object.

Here's an example:

```cs
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract void AbstractMethod();
}

class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass
{
    public override void AbstractMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a non-abstract method!");
    }
}

// Now we can create an instance of ConcreteClass
var instance = new ConcreteClass();
```

You can then call the AbstractMethod on the instance object, since it has been implemented in the ConcreteClass.

---

Also my small mistake, as @ewerspej noticed:

> IClientHandler is an **interface**, not an abstract class. Neither can be instantiated. Interfaces require implementations that can be instantiated and abstract classes must be extended by non-abstract classes that can be instantiated.

Comment: Wait tho in the abstract classes
there are things like this
`
public abstract void OnConnection(BaseEvent evt);
`

in the "concreteclass" shouldnt those things be BaseEvent too?